# How to split multiple options of an Excel form

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm doing a data cleaning on excel and it was all going fine until i need to count how many times an answer apear. It was a multiple choice so, in Excel, the column has the type:

`Answer1, Answer2, Answer4`

`Answer2`

`Answer3, Answer4`

If it was just like these (and correct me if I'm wrong) I just need to say that the coma is the separator and we can have all answer in separate and then count how many times each answer apears. However, the main problem is one of the answers has a coma on the sentence so if i do by this method, I'll not have the results i have.

Is there any solution to get how many times each options apears in this particular case?

I'm leaving an exemple so you can understand better:

`Question: Select the correct sentences:`

`Options: "Hello, my name is John"`

`"Hello, my name are John"`

`"Hello, people call me John"`

`"Hello, I'm john"`

And on excel we have the following 2 lines of exemple:

`line1: Hello, my name is John, Hello, I'm John`

`line2: Hello, I'm John, Hello, people call me John`

And i want to create a small table on excel that shows that on that two lines "Hello, my name is John" apear once, "Hello, I'm John" apear twice and "Hello, people call me John" apear once.

I've already tried to use the builtin separator of excel but with no success since all sentences have comas

I've already tried just use COUNTIF with the selected senteces to count with no results

Comment: I would look at substitute() to remove all commas then textjoin() to put them back together with a comma separator.

Answer (score 1):

With this formula

```
=SUM(IF(--ISERROR(SEARCH(I1,$A$1:$A$30))=0,1,0))
```

1. Place it in cell H1 and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (array formula)
2. Drag down H1 to the end of the used rows in I
3. In cell I1 and down place the text you want to search and count
4. Replace A$30 with the actual length of the Column A

[image]